# Multiple instances of an object inside a XIB file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib, instantiation, nswindowcontroller

I have a document-based app with the recommended `NSDocument` / `NSWindowController` setup. Every window has its own `NSWindowController` instance and an associated XIB file. The interface is loaded pretty straight-forward in `-(id)init`: `if (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"DocumentWindow"]) { // yadda yadda }`. The XIB file contains an object that represents a separate controller that should be instanciated every time the user opens a new window. It presents data that is only relevant to the current document. When I unpack the object with `-(id)initWithWindowNibName:` I always get a reference to the same instance despite having two different window controllers and despite having called `-(id)initWithWindowNibName:` twice. The XIB loading mechanism seems to only unpack the same archived object once which kind of makes sense (*really?*).

Is there no way besides allocating separate objects in code, manually loading views, calculating their sizes, adding them as subviews, then setting bindings and keeping an eye on unbinding them manually when the window gets closed?

*I’m banging my head against the wall, because of my own stupidity. It just makes things worse.*

Comment: Are you sure the object in question is actually in the XIB, and not the "file owner" (which is not actually in the XIB).

Comment: The issue was completely unrelated to the XIB loading mechanism, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As I initially thought I was absolutely on the wrong path. The issue was simply that I registered a notification in the aforementioned instantiated class for an object that was a subview of the application’s `keyWindow` (I hacked it together and wanted to change it later to a property, *ouch*). When the application was loaded all instances registered for all document windows and all of them got notified and calculated the same data.

The debugger is my best friend today.

There is actually nothing like an optimization when you unarchive objects from a XIB and you will always get different instances (which absolutely makes sense in retrospect). If you encounter a similar issue, then it’s probably an unrelated bug at another place in your code.